# Spinner with a delay to disappear!

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I created a component where I use lightning Spinner a lot, especially when I have to search for information in the Salesforce database or after some dynamic procedure on the screen, like a calculation that takes a little longer than normal.

I noticed that setting the variable to "false", to disable Spinner, it only disappears when I change the browser tab or when I minimize the browser.

**- Component**

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.loading}">
    <lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" alternativeText="Loading" 
                       size="large" class="slds-is-fixed" variant="brand"/>
</aura:if>
```

**- Controller**

```
({
sendEmailDataLoader: function(component, userEmail, tpObject, listError, 
                              csvFileError, numSuccess, csvFileSuccess) 
{
    component.set("v.loading", true);
    let action = component.get("c.sendEmailDataLoader");

    action.setParams({
        "userEmail": userEmail,
        "tpObject": tpObject,
        "numSuccess": numSuccess,
        "csvFileSuccess": csvFileSuccess,
        "listError": listError,
        "csvFileError": csvFileError
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        component.set("v.loading", false);
        let state = response.getState();

        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set('v.openImportResultModal', true);
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            this.showToast(state, response.getError());
        } else if (state === "") {
            console.log("The insert list is empty!");
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
})
```

Has anyone experienced a similar situation working with this component of ligthning? Is there another way I can force the Spinner to disappear after a screen procedure?

Comment: That's quite an odd behavior, could you please edit your question and minimal version of code for us to replicate the behavior? Seems like some JavaScript listener in your component or its component hierarchy (in case there are additional nested components) may cause this side effect.

Comment: @Raul, I put a simple example. I send email to a specific user, and regardless of whether it's successful or not, I set the variable "v.loading" to "false". The problem is that even if I set it to "false", Spinner stays on the screen, but when I change the tab or minimize the browser, Spinner disappears.

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are likely outside the Aura lifecycle.

If you are using a timeout or callback or any other async process, then you'll need `$A.getCallback()`.

Use it like this:

```
window.setTimeout(
  $A.getCallback(function() {
    component.set("v.loading",false);
  }), 5000
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to not use a Timeout? Because I expect the return of information from Apex, to warn the user that a certain process was done successfully or not, and show how many results were successful and how many were not. Consequently I disable Spinner and activate a modal to show some message to the user showing some values dynamically.

Comment: Now that you've added to your example, I would have thought that this is all within the Aura lifecycle (ie no need to use `$A.getCallback()`). You can skip the timeout of course, but you would normally need to wrap the action handler function.... eg `action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback( function(response) {}));`. Anothe way is to emit a component event and handle it in the same component - the handler would then set loading to false and you'd be back in the Aura lifecycle.